# How to evaluate whether this set is convex or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am new into convex optimization, and I am trying to solve a few questions from a book after reading its first chapter. The problem is, I am not getting the approach that I need to take to solve these questions.

For example, I need to evaluate if the following set is convex, concave or neither:

[image]

So, what I want to do is to plot the set out, so that I can then see if there can be drawn a line segment using 2 points on the set which do not pass through the set. If not, then it is convex. If yes, then it is concave. Am I right?

But I am not able to figure out how to draw the set. Could anyone help me? Or if my approach is not correct, and there is a better, more efficient approach for these kind pf problems, could anyone help me out with that as well?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on S and T

Comment: @soma But this is all that the question states. It didn't mention any specifics about S and T.

Comment: Ok, try to compute in R with S={0} and T={1}. Then try with S={0;2} and T={1}

Comment: What is the definition of a 'concave' set?

Comment: @gerw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Non-convex_set

Comment: @MichaelGrant: This is a pretty strange definition. [humor]In my opinion, a set should be called concave iff it is convex. With this definition, the maximization of concave functions over concave sets has the same property as minimization problems with convex functions over convex sets.[/humor]